# OpenCV SVM - Get Number of Classes in Multi-Class Classification

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm

I am implementing a generalized SVM Prediction Function to get the classification results based on OpenCV SVM (log odds of selecting each class). I have one question though, How can I get the number of classes the SVM was actually trained on from the SVM Model?

Any help is much appreciated :)

David

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#svm-getsupportvectors)?

Comment: Not really, I am actually looking for a way to get the number of classes the SVM was trained on. e.g. for a SVM with 4 classes( 1 : cow , 2 : horse, 3 : pig , 4 : butterfly) I would like to get a 4. In the source code of OpenCV there is a function that returns the number of classes. Unfortunatelly It has been defined as private and cannot be used.